# How can I cache android packages using squid Cache?

Tags: squid, cache

I have a wireless Access point with another system using debian and squid/dansguardian as a transparent  proxy to filter adult content. 
I can see that 90% the traffic comes from android phones and people used them to update their applications using wifi instead of using their data plan.

So I tried to force Squid to cache the apk files using those lines on /etc/squid/squid.conf:

```
acl market rep_mime_type application/vnd.android.package-delta
cache allow market
```

But when check the /var/log/squid/access.log I can not see that Squid is caching

> 1405755182.383  28048 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 5858532 GET http://r11---sn-h5q7eney.c.android.clients.google.com/market/GetBinary/GetBinary/com.whatsapp/48513:48450:2?
>   - DIRECT/74.125.168.112 application/vnd.android.package-delta

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is possible, play store now sends delta updates so even if you decide to cache that requests you would only be caching chunks of apk.
Please note that the request you posted has parameters as there is query character (?) at the end and squid won't cache those requests by default.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Caching chucks of apk would be nice. you have 100 users an only 2Mb of bandwidth every little bit helps